# Switch statement bigger than

Tags: switch-statement

How to make a switch statement condition look like this:

```
if(age>18)
```

I want it to look like this, but then in a switch-statement version.

Is this possible?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language you use.

**C#** => **Not possible**: [switch case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> Each case label specifies a **constant value**.

**Java** => **Not possible**: [switch case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> An if-then-else statement can test expressions based on ranges of
>   values or conditions, whereas a switch statement tests expressions
>   based only **on a single integer**

You will have to use an if-elseif-elseif-else approach in case you use Java or C#.

---

**Javascript** => **Possible**: [switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> case **expressionN** A case clause used to match against expression.

```
switch (true) {
  case age > 18:
    document.write("You are older than 18");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a language, but the below construct is possible in languages which take an expression in the switch, viz:

```
switch (age>18)
{
   case true:
     // Do over 18 stuff here
     break;
   case false:
     // Do under 18 stuff here
     break;
}
```

Although this works, this wouldn't be an intuitive branching technique so readability of the code may suffer - use of `if / then else` for branches, or the conditional operator for conditional evaluation would be more common.

Answer (score 0):

mostly the switch statements are used when you are exactly matching the phrase.

```
switch (age>18)
{
case true:
 //Do something
  break;
 case false:
  //Do something
   break;
  }
```

In your case use if condition.It will also gives you better way to check your data.If your age is less than 18 or any other case.

```
 if(age>18)
 {/* Do something if your condition is true  */ }
 else 
 { /* When your condition is false */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with a sort of 'reverse condition' trick - if that's supported by the language used, of course. That's how it looks in JavaScript:

```
function checkAge(age) {
  switch (true) {
    case age < 18:
      console.log('Really young');
      break;
    case age < 25:
      console.log('Young and proud');
      break;
    case age < 32:
      console.log('Mature and proud');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Well, I got some news for you...');
  }
}

checkAge(17); // Really young
checkAge(24); // Young and proud
checkAge(31); // Mature and proud
```

The trick is that each subsequent `case` value is checked against the expression specified as `switch` value. Still, as you need to delimit each section with `break`, I really doubt that's more readable than `if-else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically* you can put it like that (C# code sample):

```
switch (age) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
  ...
  case 18:
    break;
  default: // <- if(age>18)
    ...  
    break;
}
```

but do you *really* want it? In C#, Java etc. we usually use ***if else***:

```
  if (age <= 5) { // from 0 up to 5
    ...
  }
  else if (age <= 10) { // from 5 up to 10
    ...
  }
  else if (age <= 18) { // from 10 up to 18
    ...
  }
  else { // over 18
    ...
  }
```

In case of **a SQL dialect** (where often you *don't have* **if** construction) you can put it like that:

```
  case 
    when (age > 18) then
      ...
    else...
  end
```

for instance

```
  select case 
           when (age > 18) then
             'Over 18'
           else
             '18 or under 18'
         end
    from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can do:

```
switch($age) {

  case ($age < 17): 
    print "do something";
  break;
  case ($age > 18): print "over 18"; break;
}
```